# Get URL origin and parameter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I easily extract the origin and a specific parameter from the tab from where I called the extension?

If the current URL is:

```
https://base.com/etc/etc?param1=123
```

I'd want to get two variables
    origin = "https://base.com"
and 
    param1 = "123"

Ideally this should still work if there are more parameters, i.e.
if the current URL is
    https://base.com/etc/etc?param1=123&param2=234

I would still get
    origin = "https://base.com"
and 
    param1 = "123"

I understand that i could use something like

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
```

but i am learning Javascript slooowly. How would this function look like?

Comment: chrome.tabs.query is the first step, then use [URL](http://devdocs.io/dom/url) API e.g. `new URL(tabs[0].url).searchParams`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) says that in the callback `function (tabs)` you'll get an array of `Tab`. A `Tab` has a lot of properties, one of them being `url`. So you could do something like:

```
// Get the current active tab in the last focused Chrome window (before the popup showed)
// should return only ONE tab
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    if (!tabs[0]) { console.log('Could not get current tab'); return; }

    // Now extract the information from the URL
    let url = new URL(tabs[0].url);
    let base = url.protocol + '//' + url.hostname;
    let param1 = url.searchParams.get('param1');

    console.log(base);
    console.log(param1);
})
```

Comment: Thanks. My extension has a popup so I am now getting the base as chrome-extension://xxxxxxx. How can i get the tab that was active when the button to call my popup was clicked?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, you should use it the way you did before. With lastFocusedWindow: true. I changed my post so it uses that instead.

Comment: For some reason i still get the same : base = 'chrome-extension://xxxx". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try refreshing your Chrome extension so you don't have the old code cached. Go to chrome://extensions and hit Reload on your extension. Then go to www.google.com or something, then try right click on your popup icon and choose "Inspect popup".

Comment: If it works out for you, consider marking my answer as correct so that others who may stumble across this knows what to do :)

Comment: I accepted the answer. I refreshed and reinstalled the extension, still the same - my popup has a button which is the one that calls the code, could this be an issue? In any case, I can try to change my extension and remove the popup, and in that case this problem will hopefully disappear. But i wonder what i should change.